SQL: ORACLE syntax performance
Is there a more performant way to enhance the following SQL syntax on Oracle, theres around 400million records in a table, but is taking 30 seconds to execute. iTrackingLogId is an index
select max(iTrackingLogId), max(tsLog)
from NmsTrackingLogRcp
where TRUNC(tsLog) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)


hope, tsLog is date ?

And is tsLog indexed too, or only iTrackingLogId?

If I'm not mistaken, whenever you have a function in the WHERE clause, it will slow your query down.

Are there any future rows in the table? If not and if the IDs stem from increasing sequences, then your query can be simplified to select max(itrackinglogid), max(tslog) from nmstrackinglogrcp. For this query you'd only need two separate indexes, one for each of the two columns, and Oracle will get your result in the blink of an eye.

@ThorstenKettner Initially i had it like that, and realised the sequence had restarted due to reaching max 32bit length, and there is a record from January this year with a higher id than the latest records.

Assuming tsLog is indexed, you could do:
select max(iTrackingLogId), max(tsLog)
from NmsTrackingLogRcp
where tsLog >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
and tsLog < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + 1

That will allow a range search on that index, looking for any value at or after midnight today (in your session time zone, as you're using current_date not sysdate) and before midnight tomorrow.
As @ThorstenKettner pointed out in a comment, if you can't have tsLog values in the future (which is likely then you don't need the second condition as it can never be false.
When you do:
where TRUNC(tsLog) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)

then, unless you have a function-based index, you are making it apply the TRUNC() function to every row in the table to allow the truncated value to be compared, which prevents the (normal) index being used.

You are currently selecting
select max(iTrackingLogId), max(tsLog)

Those two values might not be related - the last log time might not relate to the highest ID, depending on what you are logging and how your IDs are generated.
You can use keep to get the ID corresponding to the time:
select max(iTrackingLogId) keep (dense_rank last order by tsLog),
  max(tsLog)

... although "the ID" might actually still be "an ID" depending on the precision of tsLog - it may be possible, or even likely, to have two IDs with the same time. If so then any ID may be acceptable; but you can make the result deterministic by making it ... order by tsLog, iTrackingLogId).
You could also order the whole result set by tsLog desc, iTrackingLogId desc and fetch first 1 row only to just get the first row in that ordering, instead of aggregating. Oracle will even use the index to minimise the work it does, without needing a where clause (per @Thorsten, again).

That's a very good point that the OP might just be looking for the values of today's last inserted row (where last inserted could either mean the newest timestamp or the highest ID). Maybe they could even do without the where clause.

@ThorstenKettner Initially i had no where clause, and realised the sequence had restarted due to reaching max 32bit length, and there is a record from January this year with a higher id than the latest records.
